# using unityscript to write a popup for unity 3d based app for ios

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to write apopup plugin for my unity 3d ios based app, I want to write a plugin that will create a button that will open a new window, and in the new window put a link to a website. I know how to generate a button, but then I get stuck, help any body ?!, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In case you understand plug-in as a set of GUI elements, you can use the new `ModalWindow` (v4.1.2) or make your very own custom via the `GUI` class.

http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/GUIScriptingGuide.html
http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/GUI.html

In case you don't like UnityGUI, you can get some other third-party libraries to get your job done, as NGUI: http://www.tasharen.com/?page_id=140

Take a look at Unity's Asset Store for more packages.